# Big O Runtime for Sorted Array Insert (Beginner)

Tags: arrays, big-o

The Big O runtime for inserting an item into a sorted array is O(N)

However, I was wondering why it isnt O(N^2) because wouldnt you have to first
find the correct index to place the inserted item which is O(N), then shift the rest of the data down by one to make room for this inserted item which is also O(N)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's O(N) + O(N), which is still just O(N).